# FFmpeg doesn't write to HLS output (udp multicast input)

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, udp, multicast, hls

This is the output from `ffprobe`.

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://239.0.0.80:2345?localaddr=192.168.2.127':
  Duration: N/A, start: 39580.799967, bitrate: N/A
  Program 60 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : ChannelName
      service_provider: ProviderName
    Stream #0:0[0x3d]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x40](slo): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x41](slo): Audio: ac3 ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:3[0x42](qaa): Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 0 channels, fltp
    Stream #0:4[0x43](slo): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 64 kb/s (visual impaired) (descriptions) (dependent)
    Stream #0:5[0x3e](slo): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006), 492x250
    Stream #0:6[0x44]: Unknown: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)
    Stream #0:7[0x3f](slo): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
```

Notice the weird start time, it's not at zero like a normal stream. A sample progress output: `frame=  515 fps=125 q=-1.0 size=N/A time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A`  . Negative time! Even weirder. Someone already had this problem: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3427. With the exact same time! (-577014:32:22.77). (It's already fixed. 8 years old. I definitely do not have a 8 year old FFmpeg installed.) So I really do not know if we have the exact same input, or something else. Anyways, another problem I had that I had to increase `max_muxing_queue_size` to 99999, values like under 16384 refused to work, I'm thinking this is related - but any other streams with the exact same options do output the HLS stream.

```
ffmpeg -i udp://239.0.0.80:2345?localaddr=192.168.2.127 -y -acodec aac -b:a 128k -vcodec copy -sn -map 0 -avoid_negative_ts make_zero -copyts -start_at_zero -max_muxing_queue_size 99999 -ignore_unknown -f hls -hls_time 6 -hls_list_size 4 -segment_list_flags live -hls_flags independent_segments+delete_segments -segment_wrap 8 id2/index.m3u8
```

Notice that `-avoid_negative_ts make_zero -start_at_zero` absolutely don't work. They seem ignored. What would be the issue here? Thank you all for help!

This is the output of `ffmpeg -version` (I am not using an >8 years old version)

```
built with gcc 10 (Ubuntu 10.2.1-20ubuntu1)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb11u1ubuntu1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
```

Comment: If there is an already fixed bug report, the first thing you should check is which version you are using with `ffmpeg -version` and try to install a newer one

Comment: Unfortunately, the fix was 8 years ago and I'm pretty sure my FFmpeg isn't older than 8 years.

Comment: Pretty unlikely but not impossible. Updating software should always be one of the first steps when experiencing problems. Also please edit your post with the version you are currently using.

Comment: Post full log..

Answer (score 1):

To convert an mpts UDP stream to hls, you can choose an audio stream and map the desired streams something like `-map 0:0 -map 0:1`. It will fix your current issue, but you will lose all the other streams.

Otherwise, you could use something like this :

```
`ffmpeg -i "udp://239.0.0.80:2345?localaddr=192.168.2.127&pkt_size=1316" -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:a:2 -map 0:a:4 -b:v 2000k -b:a:1 192k -b:a:2 192k -b:a:4 64k -f hls -var_stream_map "v:0,a:1,a:2,a:4" -f hls -hls_time 3 -hls_segment_type mpegts -hls_flags delete_segments -hls_segment_filename 'file_%v_%03d.ts' id2/index.m3u8`
```

In addition, please use `-hls_segment_type mpegts`, this makes things a lot more stable when transcoding a UDP mpegts stream to HLS in my experience.

Comment: Please use the appropriate code tags for commands and output.

Comment: As I'm aware, some HLS players don't support the TS container type.